# Como atualizar um DataGridView ao alterar o outro?

Tags: winforms

Tenho um `DataGridView` chamado `gridProfissional` que lista todos os profissionais que tenho cadastrado em uma tabela.

Tenho outro `DataGridView` chamado `gridAgenda` que lista os dias que o profissional atende.

Tenho uma função que funciona corretamente:

```
private void preencheGridAgenda()
{
    List<datum> listaData = new List<datum>();
    int idAgenda = Convert.ToInt32(gridProfissional.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
    listaData = modelOff.data.Where(p => p.idAgenda.Equals(idAgenda)).ToList();
    gridData.DataSource = listaData;
    gridData.Select();
}
```

Minha intenção é a seguinte: ao selecionar uma linha no `gridProfissional`, chamar a função `preencherGridAgenda` e atualizar o gridAgenda.

No evento `Scroll` do `gridProfissional` eu estou chamando a função `preencherGridAgenda`, porém, eu seleciono qualquer linha do meu `gridProfissional` e a função não é chamada.

Estou usando o evento errado (`Scroll`)? Tem outro evento próprio pra isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer isso é usando o evento [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) do `DataGridView`